# SQL Server - is there a way to convert OR conditions to UNION to improve performance (as part of execution plan, under the hood)?

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, union

Let's assume we have following query (greatly simplified, of course):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
Where A or B
```

The query takes about 30 seconds to run

When I rewrite the query as

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM MyTable Where A
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM MyTable Where B
) q
```

then I get results in about 4 seconds. I have seen the same pattern multiple times in the past - replacing OR with UNION improves performance a lot

**Question: is there a way to make SQL Server to convert all those OR conditions to UNION internally, while preparing execution plan?**

I was trying to find a query hint but no luck so far. We are using SQL Server 2016 SP2

Comment: You should be able to use a `FORCESEEK` hint, or hint undocumented trace flag 8726 using `QUERYTRACEON` (per the linked Q&A).  Let me know if that doesn't answer your question and we can reopen it.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260880/why-are-seemingly-suitable-indexes-not-used-on-a-left-join-with-or